# If $RT = TR^*$ and $R^* T= TR$, then $R \sqrt{T} = \sqrt{T} R$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This question is from an exercise in a course in Functional Analysis which I am self studying.

> Question:  Let T be a positive operator on a Hilbert Space H. Show that if $R\in L(H)$ satisfies $RT= T R^*$ and $R^* T= TR$, then $R\sqrt{T}=  \sqrt{T} R$.

Attempt: Operator T being positive implies that $\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq 0$ for every $x\in H$ and $R\sqrt{T}=  \sqrt{T} R$ implies that there exists operator S and U such that $R S^2 = U^2 R$ but how to move foreward from here and use the fact that T is positive?

Can you please give a hint or two?

Comment: Do you mean $\langle Tx,x \rangle \geq 0$? Aside from that, are you not trying to prove that $R\sqrt{T}=\sqrt{T}R$?

Comment: @NicolasAgote: That's what happens when one using "greater than" instead of ```\rangle``` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$\tag1
RT^2=TR^*T=T^2R. 
$$
Let $S=T^2$. Iterating $(1)$, you get
$$\tag2
RS^n=S^nR,\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb N. 
$$
Taking linear combinations in $(2)$,
$$\tag3
Rp(S)=p(S)R,\qquad\qquad p\in\mathbb C[x].
$$
Taking norm limits in $(3)$,
$$\tag4
Rf(S)=f(S)R,\qquad\qquad f\in C(\sigma(S)). 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)